# How to detect click events in pdf objects in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a web application in which I will be rendering some pdf objects. I want to detect the position of click inside the pdf container. OnClick event is not working. How to proceed?

Comment: how you render the pdf? using any plugin/ library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have an example that does not use jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div onmousedown="action()">
<object data="http://www.polyu.edu.hk/iaee/files/pdf-sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></object>
</div>

<p>click around the top and the bottom of the pdf for some text to display and change below this.</p>

<p id="texttyy"></p>
<p id="posy"></p>

<script>
function action() {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var cood = "(" + x + ", " + y + ")"
    if (y < 250) {
    document.getElementById("texttyy").innerHTML = "yes";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("texttyy").innerHTML = "no";
    }
    document.getElementById("posy").innerHTML = cood;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Would this be anything similar to what you want? I don't know how you want to display the pdf file, so I just assumed. (You're supposed to modify the if statement, this is just a simple example)

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. found the mistake i was doing since last 1 hr. :)

Comment: Hi @hellboy if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thank @Bradman175 . sorry for the inconvenience caused, I am new to stackoverflow. :)